# How to alter table (postgres) - add new column

Tags: postgresql

I know that for adding new column I have to make smth like :

```
alter table user add column name boolean;
```

But how to make it if I have tables with names ( `user,user_second`) .In this case it return an error like :

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user" LINE 1: alter table user add
>   column name boolean;

The reason is that 2 this table start in the same way (`user`) .How to solve it ?

Comment: Wrap the table name in quotes as User is a reserved keyword. `SELECT * FROM "User";`

Comment: Thanks ) Works )